# OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to filter a `tensorflow.dataset` by its index:

```
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((sequences_matrix, label_data.astype(np.int8)))
    dataset = dataset.cache()
    dataset = dataset.enumerate()

    @tf.function
    def filter_function(i, data):
        return i in train_index # train_index is a list of integers

    train_dataset = dataset.filter(filter_function)
```

but I get the error below :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marzi/workspace/nlp_classification/src/main.py", line 355, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "/home/marzi/workspace/nlp_classification/src/main.py", line 320, in main
    deep_learning_algo(THE_DATA, HYPER_DICT)
  File "/home/marzi/workspace/nlp_classification/src/main.py", line 226, in deep_learning_algo
    tokenizer_name=tokenizer_name
  File "/home/marzi/workspace/nlp_classification/src/train.py", line 118, in fit_normal
    train_dataset = dataset.filter(filter_function)
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1862, in filter
    return FilterDataset(self, predicate)
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 4264, in __init__
    use_legacy_function=use_legacy_function)
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3371, in __init__
    self._function = wrapper_fn.get_concrete_function()
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2939, in get_concrete_function
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2906, in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected
    graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3075, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3364, in wrapper_fn
    ret = _wrapper_helper(*args)
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3299, in _wrapper_helper
    ret = autograph.tf_convert(func, ag_ctx)(*nested_args)
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 823, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 697, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2855, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3075, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 600, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 973, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in user code:

    /home/marzi/workspace/nlp_classification/src/train.py:116 filter_function  *
        return i in train_index
    /home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:877 __bool__
        self._disallow_bool_casting()
    /home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:487 _disallow_bool_casting
        "using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool`")
    /home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nlp_classification/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:474 _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
        " indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.".format(task))

    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

But if I change the condition in the filter function from `i in train_index` to `i > 10` it works fine. I don't get what is the difference between these two conditions that make one of them raise an error and the other one not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@tf.function` will transform your operations to graph mode, and list comprehension [is not supported](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32546) in graph mode. You can instead make use of `tf.map_fn` or `tf.py_function`:

```
@tf.function
def filter_function(i, data):
    return tf.py_function(lambda x: x in train_index, inp=[i], Tout=tf.bool)
```

For instance:

```
import tensorflow as tf

train_index = [i for i in range(25) if i > 10]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(list(range(25)))
dataset = dataset.cache()
dataset = dataset.enumerate()


@tf.function
def filter_function(i, data):
    return tf.py_function(lambda x: x in train_index, inp=[i], Tout=tf.bool)


train_dataset = dataset.filter(filter_function)

for i in train_dataset:
    print(i[0].numpy())
```

```
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
```

Some more reading: [Better performance with tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function).